# cutting string down in PHP

Tags: php

I am dealing with something very simple and yet I found it very long winded to solve.

I have a string that has a webaddress managed by users... so it can be:

- foodoman.com
- https://foodomain.com
- http://www.foodomain.com
  and the list could go on?

Is there an easy way to recognise and cut it to mydomain.com only? That way it would stay unified?

```
function after ($this, $inthat) {
if (!is_bool(strpos($inthat, $this)))
return substr($inthat, strpos($inthat,$this)+strlen($this));
};
$web_data="";
if(!strpos($data["web"], "http://") {
$web_data=after ("http:\\", $data["concert_web"]);
}
if(!strpos($data["web"], "https://") {
$web_data=after ("https://", $data["concert_web"]);
}
if(!strpos($data["web"], "www") {
$web_data=after ("www", $data["concert_web"]);
}
```

I gathered that script but it doesn't feel right, is it future-proof? I am eager to learn and thank you in advance any comment.

Comment: You could make your question title clearer, and probably could have found the following link when thinking about the correct title:  http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php . However, note that www.domain.com is not the same as domain.com

Comment: `$host = parse_url($string, PHP_URL_HOST);` maybe?

Comment: yes `parse_url()` is what you are looking for.  you will still need to strip off the `www.` if you dont want it there, but that is a good start

Comment: Thank you very much all the recommendations and good practices. I am following all up to learn more. Thank you again.

Comment: I guess I wasn't sure what I was looking for so apologies for the weak title

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would personally use regex in combination with `preg_replace`. Something like this:

```
// Strings for testing the case.
$domains = [
  'foodomain.com',
  'www.foodomain.com',
  'http://foodomain.com',
  'https://www.foodomain.com',
  'https://www.foodomain.www.com',
];


$result_strings = preg_replace(
  [
    '#^https?://#', // First, remove protocol.
    '#^www.#',      // Remove www. from the beginning.
  ],
  '', // Replace by an empty string.
  $domains // You can pass your string here.
);

print_r($result_strings);  // It will output result string for each of the domains from $domains array.
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => foodomain.com
    [1] => foodomain.com
    [2] => foodomain.com
    [3] => foodomain.com
    [4] => foodomain.www.com
)
```

Comment: Or do all at once `$result_strings = preg_replace('#^https?://(www\.)?#', '', $domains);`

Comment: @revo that won't cover "www.foodomain.com" case.

Comment: And you can't include it?! `$result_strings = preg_replace('#^(https?://)?(www\.)?#', '', $domains);`

Comment: Thank you I used revo's example for the shorted coding however many thanks to @kalabro for the detailed explanation it is very useful. Much appreciate everyone's help on this matter.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a combination of [`parse_url($URL, PHP_URL_HOST)`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php) as [AbraCadaver](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2844319/abracadaver) mentioned and RegEx (via [`preg_match()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php)).

```
<?php

$URL = 'https://www.sub.domain.tld/file.php?okay=true';
preg_match('/([^\.]+\.[^\.]+)$/', parse_url($URL, PHP_URL_HOST), $m);
$DomainOnly = $m[1];

?>
```

`$DomainOnly` will be `domain.tld`. All subdomains will be trimmed off.